# How to pass a dynamic array out of function by reference c++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, reference

I am trying to make a function that modifies a int array. But the array is dynamic and pointers and references are not working. Here is an example

```
void addToArray (*int array, int position, int value) {
   *array[position] = value;
}

int *array = new int[10];
addToArray (&array, 0, 10); //crashes
```

I know this is a stupid example but I don't have the code to hand!

I think the issue is that it should be a double pointer in the function but I don't know how to use a reference with a double pointer.

EDIT --------------------------------------------
This is the code. I have found it!

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{
    int *currentBuffer = new int[numberOfNodes^2];

    this->addToBuffer(&currentBuffer, 1, 0, numberOfNodes);
    qDebug() << "Finished Initial Add";
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfNodes; i++) {
        qDebug() << currentBuffer[i];
    }
}

void MainWindow::addToBuffer(int *output[], int node, int position, int size) {
    qDebug() << "addToBuffer";
    for (int i = size * position; i < (size * (position + 1)); i++ ){
        qDebug() << "Iteration:" << i;
        if (ui->tableWidget->item(i, node)->text() != "-") {
            *output[i] = ui->tableWidget->item(i, node)->text().toInt();
        } else {
            *output[i] = 1000;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all this `*int` is totally wrong

Comment: I meant int *array XD on my phone

Comment: When you do `&array` you get a pointer *to the pointer*, it's of type `int **` and not what you want to do. Also, by using array indexing, you are actually dereferencing the pointer: For any pointer *or array* `p` and index `i` the expression `p[i]` is equivalent to `*(p + i)`. Note the dereferencing operator in `*(p + i)`.

Comment: What do you suggest?

Comment: Do you want to append elements to the array?

Comment: Guys, why the downvotes? It's a good question

Comment: Downvoting will not help him

Comment: @DimChtz I didnt down vote, but probably it is because the number of questions about passing arrays from/to functions is infinite

Comment: @tobi303 True, but still not a reason to downvote

Comment: I have found and added the code

Comment: Why `**output[]` when you need to pass a 1D array?

Comment: My answer applies to your new code the same way

Comment: Sorry. That was some of the stuff I did to try get it working. I will adit

Comment: Still no need to use ``&currentBuffer`` and ``int **output[]`` (which is triplle pointer and should not work btw) and ``*output[i]`` just use ``currentBuffer`` ``int *output`` and ``output[i]`` like DimChtz suggested in his answer.

Comment: @DimChtz just for the record: If a question has too many dupes it is actually a good [reason to close the question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions).

Comment: @tobi303 Sorry, but I prefer to help if I can, instead of just close the question. Personal opinion though.

Comment: @James I added your new code

Comment: @DimChtz it also helps to provide a link to a similar / duplicate question if appropriate

Comment: Works! I was adding pointers when I already had them!

Comment: Why do you XOR `numberOfNodes` with `2` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
void addToArray (int *array, int position, int value) {
    // removed * because array is already a pointer
    array[position] = value;
}

int *array = new int[10];
addToArray (array, 0, 10);
```

EDIT:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{
    int *currentBuffer = new int[numberOfNodes^2];

    this->addToBuffer(currentBuffer, 1, 0, numberOfNodes);
    qDebug() << "Finished Initial Add";
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfNodes; i++) {
        qDebug() << currentBuffer[i];
    }
}

void MainWindow::addToBuffer(int *output, int node, int position, int  size) {
      qDebug() << "addToBuffer";
      for (int i = size * position; i < (size * (position + 1)); i++ ){
          qDebug() << "Iteration:" << i;
          if (ui->tableWidget->item(i, node)->text() != "-") {
               output[i] = ui->tableWidget->item(i, node)->text().toInt();
          } else {
              output[i] = 1000;
          }
      }
  }
```

Comment: It would be nice if you could say what you changed, and *why* you made the change. Just showing some working code doesn't really help explaining the problems.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg You 're right. I was just thinking that if OP doesn't understand something in my answer, he will ask and I will explain him :)

Comment: Your code accesses out of bounds of `currentBuffer`